# How to measure the space or any UI element height in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need to measure the UI element's height and the space between UI elements.
I tried to use the WPF Inspector, which measures the UI element's height. But I need to measure the height between UI elements.

Button A
  ~
  |
  |
  ~ Button B

I need to measure the space between Button A and Button B .

I know some indirect way or manual ways.
Is there any direct tools available to measure this?

Comment: Width? Height? Do you want to have it programmatically your just using a tool?

Comment: Just a tool should be enough. Even WPF neutral tool is okay.If there is a tool available , i can apply for any similar cases.

Comment: What is your container ? Canvas, Grid, StackPanel ?

Comment: StackPanel.. But what i am looking for is generic tool .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why do you need to measure this?